# stale file handle on openshift pod terminal while accessing the nfs share

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, nfs, nfsclient

I have a spring boot application on openshift the application needs to connect to nfs share to create a file.
But whenever I try to access the mount point from the pod terminal I get permission denied. These ??? as shown below

```
sh-4.2$ ls -la /nfs/abc/
ls: cannot open directory /nfs/abc/: Stale file handle
sh-4.2$ ls -la /nfs/abc/ (after few seconds on the same pod terminal)
ls: cannot access /nfs/abc/: Permission denied


sh-4.2$ cd /nfs/
sh-4.2$ ls -la (The first command I tried immediately after pod creation.)
total 8
drwxr-xr-x.  1 root  root    29 Nov 29 08:20 .
drwxr-xr-x.  1 root  root    50 Nov 30 08:19 ..
drwxrwx---. 14 technical technical 8192 Nov 28 19:06 abc
sh-4.2$ ls -la(few seconds later on the same pod terminal)
ls: cannot access abc: Permission denied
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 29 Nov 29 08:20 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 50 Nov 30 08:19 ..
d?????????? ? ?    ?     ?            ? abc
```

any idea why these question marks appear?

The persistence volume for this is as shown below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: abc-tuc-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: classic-nfs
  mountOptions:
    - hard
    - nfsvers=3
  nfs:
    path: /tm03v06_vol3014
    server: tm03v06cl02.jit.abc.com
    readOnly: false
```

Comment: How are you connecting to the file share, did you create a volume? Did you create a custom storage class?

Comment: created a volume of type nfs, I updated the question with this information

Comment: Show me the output of `oc get pv`

Comment: I cannot view or list the pv I requested for , Error from server (Forbidden):

Comment: Maybe the pv is not bounded...you need to check the PV status

Comment: its bounded I see it in openshift

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can mount NFS, but user from the openshift only gets the permission question marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70072462/can-mount-nfs-but-user-from-the-openshift-only-gets-the-permission-question-mar)